# Get + Set different instance variables in same controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking at a project online and stumbled across something that I don't understand. I have multiple `Users`, each User has `Comments`. Is it ok to do both `set_user` and `get_comment` inside of the `comment_controller`? The `button_to` tag ends up passing in user, but only `params[:user_id]` is usable.

**users/index.html.erb**

```
<h3>All Users and Comments</h3>
<%= render @users %>
```

**users/_user.html.erb**

```
<h4><%= user.username %></h4>
<%= render user.comments %>

<%= button_to "Add comment to User", user_comments_path(user) %>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.order(:username)
  end

end
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_user

  def create
    @new_comment = @user.comments.create!(content: "Lorem Ipsum")
  end

  def update
    @comment.update_attributes(params.require(:comment).permit(:content))
  end

  private

    def set_user
      debugger
      @user = User.where(id: get_comment.user_id).first!
    end

    def get_comment
      @comment ||= Comment.where(id: params[:id]).first!
    end

end
```

1. Wouldn't I want to just set the user using the given `user_id`, and then the `create` action would be creating the new Comment? That means I'd have to have 2 `before_action`'s right?
2. This code works as is for the `update` action - it correctly gets `@user` and `@comment` because the comment exists. What would I need to do to make both `create` and `update` work?

Comment: It's difficult to give a clear answer because you currently do not have a form to create a comment but, instead, are hard coding in a new comment's content...which I'm sure is not the behavior you want. There a many tutorials that cover how to implement comments...

Comment: A comment in this context has the ability to have multiple pieces of content, whether it be text or other information. The button_to tag is just used to create a new Comment object for that User. The content “Lorem Ipsum” is just a placeholder for updating later for the only required field on the Comment object.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would refactor your `comments_controller.rb`:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_user
  before_action :get_comment, only: :update

  def create
    @new_comment = @user.comments.create!(content: "Lorem Ipsum")
  end

  def update
    @comment.update_attributes(params.require(:comment).permit(:content))
  end

  private

    def set_user
      debugger
      @user = User.find_by_id!(params[:user_id])
    end

    def get_comment
      @comment ||= Comment.find_by_id!(params[:id])
    end

end
```

If you have the User ID, you do want to use that to allow both of these controller methods to work. You can run the `get_comment` before action to only run for the update method.